# asterisk error:chan_sip.c:4274 __sip_reliable_xmit: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data

Tags: asterisk

I got the above error when try to connect two soft phones which is successfully registered. I was trying to make a voice call in local not connecting and instead returns the error:

```
chan_sip.c:4274 __sip_reliable_xmit: Serious Network Trouble; __sip_xmit returns error for pkt data
```

I am using asterisk 13.5.0 and not using freepbx. Simply try to make a call between two peers

Comment: consider reading the description of the asterisk tag, it says support is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Make changes to  sip.conf  edit the line   bind address like `bindaddr=0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Likly firewall or permissions(for socket) issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

OK I've just solved this issue in my network.
First of all , about the situation :  i had an "Issabel VoIP server" based on Asterisk 13 but when i wanted to make calls ,it just failed and i got the same error as yours on Asterisk CLI. I had successful ping requests from the server and extension had been registered without any errors.
Solution: I had doubt about network devices, so i installed 2 soft-phones (like 3cx or Zoiper) on my laptop and connected it straightly to the server using a LAN patch cord ( to see if there's an issue on server side or its related to my network infra.) and registered 2 extensions on my soft-phone and they called each other without problem.so i understood that its one of my network devices that was limiting the transition of VoIP packets between server and extensions . finally i got that it was my TDD-LTE Modem that intercept my connection.

**So to make long story short :**

1- First create a small network between your server and laptop

2- Register 2 extensions on your soft-phone

3- make call between them and if it goes fine , then look for an obstacle in your main network.

hope it could help you